# Template program keeps crashing

Tags: c++, crash

My program will compile and run fine but it crashes when im in the program.
Any idea why?

```
template<class T>
T findFeq (T arr1[], T target, T arrSize);

template<class T>
    T findFreq (T arr1[], T target, T arrSize){
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++){
        if (target == arr1[i])
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}

#include "Ex1.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void fillIntArray(int arr1[], int arrSize, int& spacesUsed);
void fillDoubleArray(double arr1[], int arrSize, int& spacesUsed);

int main(){
    const int SIZE = 1000;
    int itarget = 42;
    double dTarget = 42.0;
    int ispacesUsed;
        double dspacesUsed;
    int iArray[SIZE];
    double dArray[SIZE];

    fillIntArray(iArray,SIZE,ispacesUsed);
    cout << findFreq(iArray,itarget,ispacesUsed) << endl;

    fillDoubleArray(dArray,SIZE,dspacesUsed);
    cout << findFreq(dArray,dTarget,dspacesUsed) << endl;

    return 0;
}

void fillIntArray(int arr1[], int arrSize, int& spacesUsed){
    int maxSize;
    cout << "How many numbers shall i put into the Array? ";
    cin >> maxSize;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++){
            arr1[i] = (rand()% 100);
        spacesUsed++;
    }
}

void fillDoubleArray(double arr1[], int arrSize, int& spacesUsed){
    int maxSize,i = 0;
    cout << "How many numbers shall i put into the Array? ";
    cin >> maxSize;
    while (i < maxSize){
        cout << "Enter number to put in Array: ";
        cin >> arr1[i];
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Run it in the debugger or under a tool like valgrind.  Clearly templates are not crashing your program directly, since they are a compile-time, not run-time construct.  If you can't figure it out by using the debugger, try to boil it down to a simpler example and show us what errors you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems. But the problem which will cause a crash is,

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++)
```

Just imagine what if you enter `maxSize` greater than `arrSize` ? The buffer will overflow and  it causes either an **Undefined behavior or crash**. Same is applicable for `while` loop meant for filling `double` array.

On the side note, change the signature for `findFeq` to:

```
template<class T>
T findFeq (T arr1[], T target, unsigned int arrSize); // arrSize must be of integer type
```

Answer (score 0):

Problems:

- `maxSize` can be greater than `SIZE` --> **array out of bounds**
- T findFeq (T arr1[], T target, **size_t** arrSize); --> **array size should not depend on type T**
- fillDoubleArray(dArray,SIZE,**dspacesUsed**); --> this is dangerous, the 3rd argument `sdpacesUsed` **should be int& not double&**. This should not pass compile.